# Is there any physical meaning for componendo and dividendo?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know whether to ask this question in math or physics stackexchange. But, is there any physical meaning for componendo and dividendo? Why do I get the same expression back when I apply componendo and dividendo two times to a particular expression'?

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer the question of why, but we can do a calculation.

From $\dfrac{x}{y}$ we get after one application $\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$.

So from $\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$ we get $\dfrac{(x+y)+(x-y)}{(x+y)-(x-y)}$.

This simplifies to $\dfrac{2x}{2y}$, and then $\dfrac{x}{y}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometrical interpretation for $x>y>0$.

[image: figure]

Here, $\angle BAB' = \angle BCB' = \angle BC'B' = 45^\circ$.

If $|AB|$ and $|BC|$ are given, then $|AB'|$ and $|B'C'|$ can be deduced: 
$$|AB'|=|AC|/\sqrt{2}=(|AB|+|BC|)/\sqrt{2}$$ 
and
$$|B'C'|=|AC'|-|AB'|=\sqrt{2}|AB|-(|AB|+|BC|)/\sqrt{2} = (|AB|-|BC|)/\sqrt{2}. $$ 
Combining these, we get
$$ \frac{|AB'|}{|B'C'|} = \frac{|AB|+|BC|}{|AB|-|BC|}.$$

On the other hand, starting from $|AB'|$ and $|B'C'|$, a similar reasoning can be used to get
$$ \frac{|AB|}{|BC|} = \frac{|AB'|+|B'C'|}{|AB'|-|B'C'|}.$$

Plug in $|AB|=x$ and $|BC|=y$. The first part applies componendo and dividendo to $x/y$ and the second part applies it to the previous result, giving $x/y$ again.